# Update Cassandra Json Value with python Script

Tags: python, cassandra

Hi I am quite new to python. I do have following column in my Cassandra table. I need to update a certain value(set displayable to **true**) in it. How do i do this via python script?

```
{
  "rowId": "SYSTEM",
  "status": null,
  "startDate": null,
  "endDate": null,
  "creationDate": 1457051550494,
  "overview": null,
  "displayable": false,
  "checklistType": "NUMERIC"
}
```

I tried following which doesn't work. (**indentation error** expected an indented block)

```
session.execute('UPDATE CourseAssignment SET jsonObject["displayable"] = fromJson("true") WHERE "rowId" =  \'%s\'' % jsonObject["SYSTEM"]   )
```

[image: CourseAssignment table]

[image: CourseAssignment table]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot you shared, it looks like the `value` field is simply a `text` field (if that's not the case you must share the schema of the table), so you'll have to update the complete value stored in that field.

Comment: Thanks... I got the idea.